# Share files between different apps without SDCARD

Tags: android

I have two apps, lets call them A and B.

In app A I receive a zip folder to unzip and send those unzipped files to app B.

I tried to extract those files into this public directory `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS)` but my app B can't read files that app put there.

I'm sending the path to the files using `Intent`.

Any idea?

How can I achieve the expected result?

Comment: Use `FileProvider`: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html

Comment: how can I open in other app with the generated URI?

Comment: Well, to be honest, what you are trying to do is rather odd and may be somewhat difficult to implement. Usually, we are dealing with individual files being shared between apps, not collections of files. If the ZIP file has a known structure (App B knows exactly what files to find), you could pass a `Uri` pointing to the `FileProvider`'s root of that structure, and App B can create `Uri` values for each file. If the ZIP file has an arbitrary structure... other than passing a `Uri` for each file, I do not know of a good solution for you.

Comment: Yeah, I will try passing a Uri list to other app.